# Subeclipse, how to share project with existing trunk

Tags: eclipse, svn

i have a java project already versioned with tortoiseSVN. I just installed subeclipse in eclipse and i would like to manage my file with it.

When i try to share my project (right click on it > Team > share > svn) , i choose "Use existing repository location" and select my repository.

My repository have a common structure trunk/tags/branches. But in subeclipse it said that :

> The folder indicated by the URL cannot
>   already exist

So if i choose the trunk folder (where my source code is) subeclipse display an error because this folder already exist.

How can i handle my existing repository with subeclipse without creating new folders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution ! There were un problem beteween the versions of tortoise and subeclipse. I have updated the both to their last version available and every thing works great !